# Payment token becomes undefined after the Android Pay process (getPaymentToken)

Tags: react-native, braintree, android-pay, google-pay

I have referred this - https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-payments#readme

Here's my code (edited):>

```html
           const METHOD_DATA = [{
            supportedMethods: ['android-pay'],
            data: {
              merchantIdentifier: 'merchant.co.guru.media',
              supportedNetworks: ['visa', 'mastercard', 'amex'],
              countryCode: 'US',
              currencyCode: 'USD',
              environment: PaymentMethodKeys.environment,
              merchantInfo: {
                // A merchant ID is available after approval by Google.
                // @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/test-and-deploy/integration-checklist}
                merchantId: '0xxxxxxxxxxx6',
                merchantName: 'Application_Merchant'
              },
              paymentMethodTokenizationParameters: {
                tokenizationType: 'GATEWAY_TOKEN',
                parameters: {
                  gateway: 'braintree',
                  "braintree:apiVersion": "v1",
                  "braintree:sdkVersion": '2.4.0',
                  "braintree:merchantId": "jxxxxxxxxxxxxt5",
                  "braintree:clientKey": "03xxxxxxxxxxxxxxe99",
                  'braintree:tokenizationKey': 'production_xqs_jbxxxxxxbx8249xxxxxx5',
                  publicKey: 'jxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxqt',
                }
              }
            }
          }];

 const DETAILS = {
        id: 'demo',
        displayItems: [
          {
            label: 'Movie Ticket',
            amount: { currency: 'USD', value: '15.00' }
          },
          {
            label: 'Shipping',
            amount: { currency: 'USD', value: '0.00' }
          }
        ],
        total: {
          label: 'Merchant Name',
          amount: { currency: 'USD', value: '15.00' }
        },
        shippingOptions: [
          {
            id: 'economy',
            label: 'Economy Shipping',
            amount: { currency: 'USD', value: '0.00' },
            detail: 'Arrives in 3-5 days',
            selected: true
          },
          {
            id: 'express',
            label: 'Express Shipping',
            amount: { currency: 'USD', value: '5.00' },
            detail: 'Arrives tomorrow'
          }
        ]
      };

      const OPTIONS = {
        requestPayerName: true,
        requestPayerPhone: true,
        requestPayerEmail: true,
        requestShipping: true
      };

      const paymentRequest = new PaymentRequest(METHOD_DATA, DETAILS, OPTIONS);
      paymentRequest.show()
        .then(paymentResponse => {
          const { getPaymentToken } = paymentResponse.details;
          console.log('paymentResponse', JSON.stringify(getPaymentToken))
          console.log('paymentResponse', JSON.stringify(paymentResponse))
          return getPaymentToken()
            .then(paymentToken => {
              console.log('paymentToken paymentResponse', JSON.stringify(paymentToken))
                       
            });
        });
```

The problem is that as I try to execute Android Pay, it returns 'Record Not Found'

The response obtained is as follows

> {"serializedPaymentToken":"{\"error\":{\"message\":\"Record not
>   found\"},\"fieldErrors\":[]}","paymentToken":{"error":{"message":"Record
>   not
>   found"},"fieldErrors":[]},"serializedPaymenToken":"{\"error\":{\"message\":\"Record
>   not
>   found\"},\"fieldErrors\":[]}","paymenToken":{"error":{"message":"Record
>   not found"},"fieldErrors":[]}}'

Thus the token becomes undefined. Can you please let me know where the problem might be hidden. I should mention that I tried this code on a real device(with actual google pay account) and sandBox and in all cases it fails.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact support at https://support.braintreepayments.com/.
I would first try updating your Braintree Android SDK version. Google Pay was not available on v2.4.0. There have been a lot of enhancements since that version, so i would recommend updating to the most current version (currently 2.20.0).

Comment: I'm facing same issue and I am Implement this library https://github.com/JadavChirag/react-native-GPay. and Its working fine for me. It build production and development fine as well as :)

Comment: I'm still having the exact same problem. Did you find any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `https://google.com/pay` under `supportedMethods` instead of `android-pay` in order to leverage Google Pay through Payment Request API.

Check these couple of examples for further reference: [official docs](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/payments/merchant-guide/deep-dive-into-payment-request#payment_method_basic-card), [sample from the Chrome team](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/paymentrequest/google-pay/demo.js).